# как получить данные с aspx страницы?

Tags: php, xml

я хочу парсить xml документ который находится на другом сайте. все хорошо, если я его скачиваю в ручную как xml документ, но если я хочу получить на прямую данные с

```
$xml = file_get_contents("http://www.blueshop.pl/sklepy.aspx");
```

то получаю ошибку

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.blueshop.pl/sklepy.aspx): failed
>   to open stream: HTTP request failed!

в чем проблема? я так понимаю из за того что это aspx страница?

Comment: нет. скорее всего вы делаете это на каком-либо хостинге, который запрещает функции вида `file_get_contents` .......а если на локалке... то в `php.ini` возможно отключена `allow_open_url`

Comment: нет, с другими файлами работает, а именно с этим нет

Comment: Ну значит страницу глючит...т.к. если перейти по этой ссылке то сама страница будет сто лет грузиться.... а `file_get_contents` работает....

Answer (score 1):

решил проблему использовав curl, не знаю правильный ли способ, но хотя бы работает...

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.blueshop.pl/sklepy.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$file = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$xml = simplexml_load_string($file);
foreach ($xml->PRODUCT as $child)
{
        echo $child->NAME."<br/>";

}
```